# Error launching Chrome with Selenium WebDriver in Java Eclipse -Exception in thread "main"

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I got this error message when I try to launch Chrome with Selenium WebDriver in Java Eclipse. (Java Eclipse is in USB stick)
Java code -
package SeleniumSessions;

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class WebDriverBasics {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // chrome browser 
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\waychal\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe"); 

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  // launch Chrome browser
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");


   }

}
```

Error messages-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:847)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:134)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
at SeleniumSessions.WebDriverBasics.main(WebDriverBasics.java:15)
```

Comment: Please verify that your geckoDriver.exe is located in correct folder or not.

Comment: The problem is that, you are using webdriver.gecko.driver, which is used to access firefox.  To set the path of the chromedriver you need to replace webdriver.gecko.driver with webdriver.chrome.driver

Comment: you can also try putting a try-catch for 3s inside the main method.
try {
   Thread.sleep(3000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception asks for a path to the chrome driver

```
The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property
```

You are setting it for the gecko driver

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
```

I don't exactly know but I would recommend you to use the Chromedriver and also set the correct property.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I had already resolved this Problem after posting this question :D. I had tried the sample program from youtube which was for Mac user and hence gecodriver.